# New line escape characters

Tags: java

To Whom It May Concern,

I am trying to compile a progam in Java using a single print line. I was tasked to use escape sequences and the error I got was illegal escape character. Here is the output I'm aiming for. Output I want:

```
Alpha
Bravo
Charlie
Delta

EchoFoxtrotGolf
Hotel
India

This is a test.
```

Here is my code:

```
public class PrintingChoicesEscapesSecond {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Alpha\n\Bravo\n\n\Charlie\n\Delta\n\n\EchoFoxtrotGolf\n\Hotel\n\n\India\n\n\This is a test. );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try the following code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Alpha").append("\n")
  .append("Bravo").append("\n")
  .append("Charlie").append("\n")
  .append("Delta").append("\n").append("\n")
  .append("Echo").append("Foxtrot").append("Golf").append("\n")
  .append("Hotel").append("\n")
  .append("India").append("\n").append("\n")
  .append("This is a test");

String formattedString = sb.toString();
System.out.println(formattedString);
```

Comment: Rahul, thank you for your response as well. Now, I'm not familiar with this format but I'll give it a shot. Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- You are missing a closing quotation mark
- You have `\` after `\n` which will try to escape the next letter, which is not what you want.

So in the `String`:

```
Alpha\n\Bravo
       ^^ this \ is trying to escape B which is invalid.
```

Remove the trailing `\`. Also you have a a few extra `\n`'s to get the output you want.(Extra one after Bravo, and Hotel):

```
System.out.println("Alpha\nBravo\nCharlie\nDelta\n\nEchoFoxtrotGolf\nHotel\nIndia\n\nThis is a test. ");
```

***Output:***

```
Alpha
Bravo
Charlie
Delta

EchoFoxtrotGolf
Hotel
India

This is a test.
```

Comment: GBlodgett, thank you very much for your help. I'm just seeing it now. Thank you

Comment: @user2727050 If an answer was helpful to you, you have the option to accept the answer by clicking the green check mark underneath the vote count on the answer (It'll give you some reputation)